# Ubuntu 20.04 Freeze on loading screen. Have Intel UHD 620 graphics

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and my computer is freezing solid on the login screen. Have to hard reset holding the power button.

Initially, I had Mate 20.04 installed (I believe in April) and it worked great till Aug.

I have since tried several full clean installs (Actually new OS on / and keeping my same personal data on /home). All new installs fail to get past the login screen.

Currently, I am trying Ubuntu (not mate) 20.04. It will boot if I place this command in the boot grub: "intel_idle.max_cstate=1", but then the cpu n fan run constantly.

I have tried adding "dis_ucod_ldr to teh /etc/default/grub, as it has been linked to freezing on Intel UHD 620 cards.
I have also updated to the latest EFI bios... no impact.

I am currently using the latest ubuntu kernel 5.11.0-36-generic
But have the same issue using various 5.4 or 5.8 kernels

I believe the following may be helpful. It is what I get when booted using "intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

Thanks Mark

> inxi -G Graphics:
> Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v:kernel
> Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev
> unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
> OpenGL:renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
>
> sudo lshw -C video   *-display
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: UHD Graphics 620
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 2
> bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
> version: 07
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
> configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
> resources: irq:128 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
>
> sudo lshw -C cpu   *-cpu
> description: CPU
> product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
> vendor: Intel Corp.
> physical id: 12
> bus info: cpu@0
> version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
> serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
> slot: U3E1
> size: 3399MHz
> capacity: 4005MHz
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 100MHz
> capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi